# How did you cope/deal with

Tags: difference, idiomatic-language

How did you cope/deal with the divorce?

- I am aware of the technical difference between using "cope with" and "deal with" but are they used interchangeably in a context like this?
- Are they equally formal/informal?

Comment: You have not given any context. Do you mean legally, practically, emotionally or all of them? Who instigated the divorce?

Comment: Mainly emotionally. Mutual decision.

Comment: In that case I would say "cope" is better.

Comment: @Weather Vane I agree. *coping with* often has emotional overtones (how did you deal with anger, distress and rejection?) whereas *dealing with* is predominantly practical things (what were the legal aspects, what did you do about money, house, children ...).

Comment: "Dealing" with something can be just a job to do, whereas "coping" implies difficulty.

Comment: What @Anton said. Often, to ***deal with*** something and to ***cope with*** it are equivalent, but the former is much more likely in the context of resolving *practicalities*, whereas the latter is more likely to involve *emotional* reactions.

Answer (score 0):

They are similar. You **deal with** an **issue** and you *cope with* a *problem*. In other words, to me "deal with" does not imply that there is a difficult or problematic situation, although there might be. "Cope with" implies that there is a problem one has to manage.

## Attribution

https://www.lingq.com/en/forum/learning-english-forum-ask-a-tutor/deal-with-or-cope-with/